# Unity iOS build linking error in Xcode

Tags: c#, ios, xcode, unity-game-engine

I'm currently working on game and I'm pretty much done with it. I've developed this game by unity on Windows and now I want to build it on a mac using Xcode. But when I'm building it on Xcode it comes up with 3 linking errors and I have been trying to solve it for someday. But unfortunately I couldn't come up with any solution. The screenshot of errors is:

[image: Xcode error log]

Please someone help me solving this problem.

Comment: What is the build target set to in the Unity editor?  It should be under your Player Settings.

Comment: target is set to 9. But I've found the solution. Linking error is caused by may reasons. My reason was in unity I had a duplicate game object in 2 different scenes. Xcode gives error in linking if there are any duplicate method..